# GET / 404 Not Found on ngrok

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I wanted to expose a NodeJS app running on port 3000 using ngrok. I don't find any logged error messages, that could guide me. I am new to ngrok, and am not sure, what's the mistake. Does the location where it its installed matter. I think, ngrok hasn't been added to PATH variable on windows.

Please help on this.

Comment: are you able to run the ngrok command? if yes it must return you a path

Comment: Yes, am able to run.

Comment: which path are you hitting?